# Programmatically change eCommerce product's currently used URL

Tags: c#, sitefinity

Heyo,

We're creating products (in the eCommerce module) with the same names quite often (e.g.: `Red T-Shirt` with SKU 123, and another `Red T-Shirt` with SKU 4500) which results in the URLs of the products being the same (e.g.: `"/red-t-shirt"`)

The problem as you may know is that you can't have two products with the same URL (or the same *additional URLs*) - this results in an exception being thrown whenever you try to save one of the products with the same name (and will appear as an undefined error in the Sitefinity UI).

When these products get created I'd like to do a search for other products with the same URL so I can change its URL to something else (e.g. the new `Red T-Shirt` will get `"/red-t-shirt"` automatically, the old one will change to something else)

I'd also like to do the same with the additional URLs. **Currently I'm doing both with SQL but I'd like to do it with C# instead**. This is what my SQL looks like - I just have no idea how it translates to C#.

```
-- Change URLs in sf_url_data, the 'additional URLs'
SELECT *
FROM dbo.sf_url_data
WHERE 
    (url LIKE '%/red-t-shirt%') 
AND 
    (content_id IN
        (SELECT id
        FROM dbo.sf_ec_product
        WHERE (sku <> 4500))) -- 4500 is the new PLU that we want to keep as /red-t-shirt

--
-- Change URLs in sf_ec_product, the default URL
SELECT *
FROM dbo.sf_ec_product
WHERE 
    (id IN
        (SELECT content_id
        FROM dbo.sf_url_data
        WHERE (url LIKE '%/red-t-shirt%')))
```

Note I have to change the additional URLs first because I use the `sf_ec_product`'s actual URL to do the select for additional ones (see the sub-query).

---

**EDIT**: I'm looking for a solution that should (I assume) make use of the Sitefinity `CatalogManager` class, as described here: https://docs.sitefinity.com/for-developers-modify-products

Comment: you just need to look at converting your SQL queries into LINQ. I would post this an answer but I think, its fairly obvious that is what needs to be done. Unless your requirement is more specific in which case we can provide a better answer.

Comment: The problem is the Sitefinity tables aren't exposed like they are with an entity data model, you can't just grab the records by using `db.sf_ec_products`, you have to use a module manager similar to how you retrieve dynamic content with the dynamic module manager. I just don't know how to do that for products. Thank you though!

Comment: why not run a SQL query to get all of them into a collection (like a List<YourProductType> and then apply LINQ to this collection? That is what I would do in your place. That would avoid having to use SQL for every query. You just need to write some kind of helper which can be used everywhere and problem solved.

Comment: I just think there is a neater, Sitefinity-specific way to do that without making an ADO .NET connection and playing with the database directly. The Sitefinity database is almost never (I've yet to see an example) touched directly, instead the actual Sitefinity libraries have specific classes and methods for manipulating the data. Your solution could work, but I just know there's a better one out there.

Comment: sounds like a plan.

Comment: I found what I was looking for - see my answer below if you're curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. This *should* work.

```
CatalogManager catalogManager = CatalogManager.GetManager();

// Get the old unused product
Product oldProduct = catalogManager.GetProduct(oldProduct.Sku, ContentLifecycleStatus.Live);

// Set the english and french URLs to something new
oldProduct.UrlName.SetString(enCulture, "new-english-url");
oldProduct.UrlName.SetString(frCulture, "new-french-url");

// Delete associated non-default URLs
List<ProductUrlData> urls = oldProduct.Urls.Where(u => !u.IsDefault).ToList();
if (urls.Count > 1)
{
    oldProduct.Urls.ClearUrls(true);
    for (int i = urls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        catalogManager.Provider.Delete(urls[i]);
    }
}

// Recompile the URLs and save changes
catalogManager.Provider.RecompileItemUrls(oldProduct);
catalogManager.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: CatalogManager is the library provided function. nice.